# Plans for Socket api for dart in chrome apps

Tags: sockets, google-chrome, dart

Is there any plan to allow dart programs to use sockets in chrome, like chrome packaged apps are allowed to use the chrome.socket api set?

Answer (score 1):

There is a package which implements the chrome* APIs in Dart at http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/chrome.

Comment: These wrap the javascript APIs. I was hoping for the same APIs that are available for dart command line apps. One deployment that is mentioned in the docs for dart apps is that one can use a pure dart VM without the javascript engine. The chrome* APIs would not work in that deployment. Or will they? Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Sockets are supported by latest releases of Dart: see [Socket](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/Socket.html) class in `dart:io` library.

They can only be used in command line applications (e.g. on server-side). Sockets are currently not supported by Web browsers (you must use [WebSockets](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/WebSocket.html) which are not the same).

Comment: Yup. Though, I'm hoping for the same APIs in the browser. See my comment to Jesse's answer.